# Is there a way to see outbound symbolic links?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, symlink

I know how to see and inbound symbolic links as follows:

I can simply use `ls -al` and will see entries like

> lrwxr-xr-x    1 c     staff     32 Oct 28 11:14 .zshrc ->
> /Users/c/top/ll/config/zshell.sh

where the link flag is set and I can see the connected real file.

But if I look at the real file in the same manner I can not see that is used to create a symbolic link:

> -rw-r--r--   1 c  staff   2152 Oct 27 17:52 zshell.sh

Comment: Your choice of terminology seems odd to me: a symbolic link is a marker pointing at something (potentially something that doesn't even exist), so I'm not sure in what sense it's "inbound". The normal term would be that the link has a "target", so what you are asking for is "find all symbolic links pointing to a particular target". That might help you search for existing answers.

Comment: Trying to build this kind of bidirectional tracking at an OS level would be... very weird. The user who owns a file may not have permissions to know that symlinks pointing to that file exist (even if they have permissions to the symlink itself, they may not have permissions to its parent directory). So trying to maintain an index to allow fast reverse lookups would involve having a more-privileged process needing to be used to check the index, but then filter results carefully to make sure a less-privileged process is actually allowed to know about them.

Comment: If you don't care about performance, this all gets much easier -- no need for an index, one can just use `find`-esque tools that walk the tree, do a resolution process and a comparison -- and in practice, that's what you're going to find by way of existing solutions.

Comment: @clarissa, you ask to see outbound links, but `ls -al` shows you the outbound link, so if you know where it is to read it by name (or run `ls` against it), you already to know how to do what you're looking for. From the perspective of the target file, the links pointing to it are inbound; it's only from the perspective of the link itself that it's outbound.

Comment: If you know the source, you can see the target. If you know the target, there is no way to see the source(s) without scanning the file system. (Or, `ls -l` will show you the single outgoing edge from a symlink, but there is no way to see what incoming edges terminate at a given file.)

Comment: Which "that"? Do you mean it's a question of how to do something like a brute-force `find` walk of the filesystem tree looking for links with a given target?

Comment: `zshell.sh` wasn't "used" in any sense to create the link.

Comment: I don't understand this question. An object such as the `zshell.sh` file has no idea that a symbolic link is pointing at it.   Your questions is like, why doesn't a certain web page show me all the links everywhere on the web which point to that page?

Answer (score 2):

A symbolic link is best viewed not like a relationship with two ends, but like a text file containing a file path, which is automatically read by file system commands. As such, the file system never knows which paths are currently the target of a symbolic link. Indeed, **the target might be non-existent, or on a different file system**.

The best you can do is search the file system (or a particular subset where you think a link might be) for any symbolic links matching a particular path. The Swiss Army Knife that is the Unix "find" command offers an option for this:

> -lname pattern
>
> File is a symbolic link whose contents match shell pattern `pattern`.  The metacharacters do not treat '/' or '.' specially.  If the -L option or the -follow option is in effect, this test returns false unless the symbolic link is broken.

So in your example, you could run this to hunt through your entire mounted file system for links to the given file:

```
find / -lname /Users/c/top/ll/config/zshell.sh
```

Beware however that **symlinks can also be relative**, so **the target may depend both on the contents and the location of the symlink**. For instance, a link in `/Users/c/top/` could have a target of "./ll/config/zshell.sh", and would not be found by that pattern. You could broaden the pattern to "*/zshell.sh", but would then have to check the results for which ones actually resolved to your desired target.

Comment: To be more explicit, the target of a symlink may depend both on the contents *and* the location of the symlink.

Comment: @chepner Nicely summarised; I've stolen that wording for my last paragraph. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no tracking like that. Symbolic links are essentially just small text files that are treated specially; in fact, they don't always even refer to real files that exist.